# display mutiple C++ images on after another using splashkit

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble displaying multiple images using C++/splashkit.

Everything looks right but only the first image is displayed.

I've created the procedures and called them but only the first image shows up.

The code looks right but no luck. Any help?

This is the code:

```
#include "splashkit.h"
    void house_drawing()

    {
        clear_screen(COLOR_WHITE);
        fill_ellipse(COLOR_GREEN, 0, 400, 800, 400);
        fill_rectangle(COLOR_BEIGE, 300, 300, 200, 200);
        fill_triangle(COLOR_RED, 250, 300, 400, 150, 550, 300);
        refresh_screen(60);
    }

    void daves_drawing()

    {
        clear_screen(COLOR_WHITE);
        fill_ellipse(COLOR_BROWN, 0, 300, 400, 300);
        fill_rectangle(COLOR_YELLOW, 200, 300, 100, 200);
        fill_triangle(COLOR_PURPLE, 250, 250, 300, 200, 400, 300);
        refresh_screen(60);
        }

    int main()

    {
       open_window("Shapes by dave", 800, 600);

       house_drawing();
       delay(1200);


       open_window("daves Drawing", 800, 600);

       daves_drawing();
       delay(1200);


       open_window("Shapes by dave", 800, 600);

       house_drawing();
       delay(1200);



       open_window("Daves Drawing", 800, 600); 

       daves_drawing();
       delay(1200);



        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to write `clear_screen();` to clear the screen after calling a function.

Also, you don't need to open windows again and again. Just open a window once and call the first and write `clear_screen();`.

Your code sould then like this.

```
#include "splashkit.h"
    
void house_drawing()
    {
        clear_screen(COLOR_WHITE);
        fill_ellipse(COLOR_GREEN, 0, 400, 800, 400);
        fill_rectangle(COLOR_BEIGE, 300, 300, 200, 200);
        fill_triangle(COLOR_RED, 250, 300, 400, 150, 550, 300);
        refresh_screen(60);
    }

    void daves_drawing()
    {
        clear_screen(COLOR_WHITE);
        fill_ellipse(COLOR_BROWN, 0, 300, 400, 300);
        fill_rectangle(COLOR_YELLOW, 200, 300, 100, 200);
        fill_triangle(COLOR_PURPLE, 250, 250, 300, 200, 400, 300);
        refresh_screen(60);
        }

    int main()

    {
       open_window("Shapes by dave", 800, 600);
       house_drawing();
       delay(1200);
       clear_screen();
       daves_drawing();
       delay(1200);

        return 0;
    }
```